# Knockout computed function called "too late"...?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need a knockout computed function to execute directly, but it seems more like knockout queues computables and executes when it feels like it. is there a way (apart from not using knockout) to get immediate execution?

I have stepped through my code and seen that my routine continues past the call to the computed function and later I stop at a breakpoint in the function - when it's too late.

I have removed 95% of the code but the variable names are still there and they might look a bit odd in this context...

```
var self = this;
self.temp = true;

self.UsePatterns = ko.observable(false); 

self.UsePatterns.subscribe(function () {
    self.ShowReport();
});

self.PatternColors = ko.computed(function () {
    var retValue = self.UsePatterns() ? true : false
    return retValue;
});

self.ShowReport = function () {
    self.temp = self.PatternColors();
    alert (self.temp);
};

self.UsePatterns(true);
self.UsePatterns(false);
self.UsePatterns(true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tommypeters/1ubfa4ev/22/

One would think this should get true, false, true and not the reverse...

Comment: If you create the subscription after the computed, or don't make PatternColors a computed, you get what you want.  However - it seems odd to be calling computed functions directly like this - they're more designed to be used in bindings etc.  Both of these coupled together suggest that perhaps this isn't the best approach to the problem you're tying to solve here?

Comment: At least in my fiddle, if I create the subscription after the computed then nothing happens at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ko.pureComputed()` instead.

```js
var self = this;
self.temp = true;

self.UsePatterns = ko.observable(false); 

self.UsePatterns.subscribe(function (nv) {
    self.ShowReport();
});

self.PatternColors = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var retValue = self.UsePatterns() ? true : false
    return retValue;
});

self.ShowReport = function () {
    self.temp = self.PatternColors();
    console.log('Show report:',self.temp);
};

self.UsePatterns(true);
self.UsePatterns(false);
self.UsePatterns(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks,

it sure works. I can’t, however, see anything in the knockout docs that indicates this as a difference between a “standard” computed observable and a pure one…

https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html

Comment: The best thing is of course that it not only works in this very stripped-down example but also in my real program :-)

Comment: @TommyPetersson the reason for the difference between the PureComputed and Computed is the fact that the Computed is evaluated immediately after its created to get its initial state, where as the PureComputed is evaluated when it is called. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html

Comment: Well, I think it was not a very clear read in the docs on pure computed computable: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html It can either be _sleeping_ or operate "just like a regular computed observable". Doesn't matter now, I got a helping answer :-)